# Hadoop,Hbase - Column and corresponding value extract

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am new to `hbase` and I have a query like how can I extract the column name and its corresponding value alone from `hbase` to an `excel/csv`.

I have tried possible scenarios like

- writing exporting the entire data `hbase`
- shell to our local location but it hasn't worked.

Can someone give me a solution

so for showing example

```
cf:ABC timestamp=1234, value=qwer
cf:DEF timestamp=5678, value=9874
cf:GEH  timestamp=10254, value=11223344
```

If this is our data then our final result should be
    ABC qwer

```
DEF 9874

GEH 11223344
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to export HBase data to csv one of the approach is to create Hive `EXTERNAL TABLE` mapped with HBase table using `HBaseStorageHandler`.

First you have to make sure HBase dependencies are available on Hive’s classpath.
The storage handle `hive-hbase-handler-x.y.z.jar`, which must be available on the Hive client auxpath, along with HBase, Guava and ZooKeeper jars.

Lets say you have `abc` table in HBase which you have to mapped with hive table.

You can give Hive access to an existing HBase table, use `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE`:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hive_table(rowkey int, ABC string,DEF string,GEH string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:ABC,cf1:DEF,cf1:GEH")
TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "abc");
```

Use HBase shell to verify data

```
>scan "abc"
```

Again query back to hive

```
hive>  select * from hive_table limit 10;
```

Now you have data in hive external table so you can export it to csv file with `,` separator.

Answer (score 0):

Use `hbase shell` with a a get or scan and pipe the output to a `sed` command to extract colunn name and value.

But warning, HBase is designed to store millions or potentially billions of rows, so extracting data to csv format is not a proper use case, unless you simply need to check which values are stored in rowkey XXX.